# Can't force game to use dedicated graphics card

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I am new to these forums, so I don't know if this is the right place to ask but...

I recently purchased a new laptop, the Thinkpad P53s, which comes with an NVIDIA Quadro P520 Graphics Card.

I have been trying to play games on the laptop, specifically Risk of Rain 2 and Hollow Night, and both games have a similar problem: The game will run smoothly most of the time, then periodically, the frame rate will drop for around 30-60 seconds before returning to the original framerate. When this happens, my task manager also shows that the Integrated Intel Processor suddenly is maxxed out in its performance (at 100%) while the NVIDIA card has Dropped to almost no use (10-15%) from its usual 75%.

I have tried every solution that I have found online:
I have set the Settings for the app to be "High Performance" in the Windows 10 display settings
I have set the game's preferred graphics card in the NVIDIA Control Panel to "High-Performance NVIDIA processor"
I have used the right-click context menu to "Run application with graphics processor > High-Performance NVIDIA".

Despite trying all of these. The program will STILL switch between the integrated graphics and the NVIDIA card.

The NVIDIA card clearly THINKS the game is running on it because the NVIDIA card taskbar menu shows Risk of Rain 2.exe running on the card; however, the actual performance of the processors says otherwise.

Again, I know this because EVERY time it lags, my task-manager shows that the NVIDIA card drops from 75 - 85% to 10-15% in the 3D category, while my Integrated Intel Processor rises from 10-15% up to 100%.

Thank you in advance for any help You can give. I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time now, so assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZm6VtNN0g8 - does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I already set that setting in the 'graphics settings' directly on windows 10 AND on the graphics setting of my specific graphics driver, but no luck...